# How do I decide what CPU to buy?

Tags: cpu, htpc

I'm building an HTPC and I already have a motherboard with an Intel socket 1150 -- but **how do I decide what specific CPU to get?**

I'm happy with the Core i7 in my desktop but for cost reasons I'll settle for a Core i5 or even a Core i3... but oven with those loose limits there are still so many to choose from. How can I make a decision about i3 or i5, and about speed? And then there are letters like K, S, etc.

I feel overwhelmed. Can you point me to some factors I can consider, to narrow down my list of options?

Comment: Feel free to drop by [Root Access](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) to consult with us about this purchasing decision. But in my opinion this question is either too broad or off-topic due to product recommendation. It's not a good fit for the site.

Comment: This is off topic for SuperUser, but you should think about what you want to do with your HTPC and visit [XBMC](http://forum.xbmc.org/forumdisplay.php?fid=112)'s forum to get some idea the processing power you need for what you want to do.

Comment: Figure out your budget, then look at the [cpu comparisons](http://www.anandtech.com/Bench/CPU/2), buy the fastest one you can afford?

Comment: @allquixotic, why would you say this is off topic for SU? It seems to me as less about a product recommendation request, and more of a knowledge request; as in the difference between "What shirt should I buy?" and "How do I know what shirt to buy?". The former has answers of specific products, the latter has answers of how to tell what size you are, what material to choose, etc. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @TorpedoBench Because even the criteria for choosing a CPU are too broad to enumerate properly in an answer less than 10 pages long. *Exceedingly* long answers are discouraged on the network because most people won't bother to read if they see a wall of text and scroll down and down and down and see more, more, more, more text. To give a proper treatment of this subject that would apply to more people than just Torben Gundtofte-Bruun, would require a longer answer than most people are willing to accept, and probably more knowledge than any one individual would have.

Comment: Also, any answer that *doesn't* cover all the bases will end up missing out on entire classes of use cases or product choices that are viable under certain conditions, and these omissions will inevitably lead to comment wars where people say "you forgot about X", then it will go back and forth between the answerer and people trying to point out what they missed. There's no way to *concisely* answer this question while still providing enough information to completely answer the question.

Comment: Aha, I see your point. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest buying a quad-core i5. There are various options for the 1150 socket, but the 4670K is probably one of the best. We're running it in a few computers and it's very nice. [Intel i5 4670K on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CO8TBOW). K is unlocked, S is performance optimized, and T is power-optimized.

Comment: S is *not* 'performance-optimized'. S is lower voltage than the base model, and has a lower TDP. So it is actually a worse performer (ever so slightly) than the base model, but it uses less energy.

Comment: I simply said what I read on Intel's own website regarding the second, third, and fourth generation Core processors. Here's a [link](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-numbers.html)